# How to redirect user to homepage after email confirmation?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to redirect users to the homepage after they click on the email verification link. However, it is not redirecting to the `return URL` as specified.

```
            EmailConfirmationUrl = Url.Page(
                "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                pageHandler: null,
                values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = "/Index" },
                protocol: Request.Scheme);
```

How can I return the user to the home page which is `/Index` after they click on the email confirmation URL? Currently, it stuck on a page with Confirm Email title only. Example of the EmailConfirmationUrl as below when I tried to test it to redirect to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) upon clicking on the URL:

```
https://localhost:44376/Identity/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=1bc31c65-1a8d-4511-9399-af83c2a98285&code=Q2ZESjhPRkRBdzJRNVE1T29wbGF6UnhpSUY5ZWk0dDlDc3U5WEcrUnBxVlNwTlpscmpzaXdSbk5XVnE1RWVxZmUyc2dRNTF4R0xtNG5yZUN1WldDb0RWK2hud0dZKzV3bFlLYVNYdDAvSFZrUEIvMEZ5cDFFRld5OEVlOE1pVmdiMDZVSERTUU5yZGIwMEhOWTdzcFkvMDRacjkwZmtSUXExUHlZb0RLMXc4RFJhNVN2NnVsVks5WVQ5cm1iZWVRTU94RUJBVFBOV0RqcmxkMDdSWGZSTVBHVHk1Y3FyVmZIK0FGQmpHMlNja1BpY21UMkZGcXBFTmhFWHZwdFAyRXNVUEc0QT09&returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F
```

Comment: Are you using Razor Pages or MVC?

Comment: You must redirect within your Controller Method or Razor Page Model. Please share your Controller Action Methods for Email Confirmation...

Comment: @MosiaThabo I am using Razor Pages

Comment: Share your OnGet method... Code

Comment: @MosiaThabo I have found the solution which is to create /Account/ConfirmEmail page model and then set the redirect in the page model. Just realised it has nothing to do with return URL in the EmailVerificationURL.

Comment: You should've done that in the first place @John Ho

Answer (score 0):

In your ConfirmEmail.cshtml.cs, configure your `OnGet` as follows. It may possibly be an `async` method because I remember `UserManager` has an `async` method `ConfirmEmailAsync`.

```
public IActionResult OnGet(int userId, string code, string returnUrl)
{
    // Perform your confirmation check.
    
    // And then redirect if passed.
    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```